# Add class to drupal body

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can I add term id of all terms related to a node, to that node body class in drupal site?

For example, A node named `stackoverflow` is tagged with four terms

```
term1
term2
term3
term4
term5
```

I want to add these classed to node body class...

```
article-term-(term1tid) 
article-term-(term2tid)
article-term-(term3tid) 
article-term-(term4tid)
article-term-(term5tid)
```

These are pages I want to change their class names:

- [عکس نوزاد](http://radiokodak.com/article/927/50)
- [عکس نوزاد](http://radiokodak.com/article/1449/180)
- [کاردستی](http://radiokodak.com/article/1484/4)
- [سوپ ساده](http://radiokodak.com/article/1416/20)
- [داستان برای کودک](http://radiokodak.com/article/1328/1)
- [کاردستی](http://radiokodak.com/term/48/600)

Comment: you mean 5 terms, right?

Comment: The last sample is different from the others as it's a term page. What body class do you need there? Where should it come from? Do the terms have fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

leymannx code is really complete and fine.

But it does not contains all terms of a node.

I wrote this code and i wish it will be useful for you.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

    if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
        $node    = node_load(arg(1));
        $results = stackoverflow_taxonomy_node_get_terms($node);
        if (is_array($results)) {
            foreach ($results as $item) {
                $variables['classes_array'][] = "article-term-" . $item->tid;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is a function named ""stackoverflow_taxonomy_node_get_terms"" that returns all terms attached to a node.

```
function stackoverflow_taxonomy_node_get_terms($node, $key = 'tid'){
    static $terms;
    if (!isset($terms[$node->vid][$key])) {
        $query   = db_select('taxonomy_index', 'r');
        $t_alias = $query->join('taxonomy_term_data', 't', 'r.tid = t.tid');
        $v_alias = $query->join('taxonomy_vocabulary', 'v', 't.vid = v.vid');
        $query->fields($t_alias);
        $query->condition("r.nid", $node->nid);
        $result                  = $query->execute();
        $terms[$node->vid][$key] = array();
        foreach ($result as $term) {
            $terms[$node->vid][$key][$term->$key] = $term;
        }
    }
    return $terms[$node->vid][$key];
}
```

i wish this code could be the best.

write all of this codes in template.php file in your theme.

if you want just some nodes have class name, add replace this part of code.

```
> if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && ( arg(1)==X || arg(1)==Y
> )  ) {
```

Comment: Great work! Please have a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards and fix your indentation (two spaces only).

Answer (score 2):

As @P1ratRuleZZZ already pointed out [`template_preprocess_html`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x) (implemented from your sub-theme's `template.php` file) is the function to add body classes.

Thing is, that within this function, you need to load the actual node object first, then get the values of that term reference field, to finally add them as classes to the body tag.

Replace `MYTHEME` and `field_MYFIELD` with your names.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_html().
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {

  // Get the node.
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {

    // Check node type.
    if ($node->type === 'article') {

      // Get taxonomy terms.
      $terms = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_MYFIELD');

      foreach ($terms as $term) {
        // Add body class.
        $variables['classes_array'][] = 'article-term-' . $term['tid'];
      }
    }        
  }
}
```

Comment: this code is really awesome but i want a code to work with all terms of a specific node.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use template_preprocess_html()

this is in your theme's template.php file:

```
YOURTHEMENAME_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $term_id = arg(1); // For example, or use some &drupal_static() to store a value while preprocessing from module
  $variables['classes_array'][] = 'article-term-' . $term_id;
}
```

So as you can see it you shoud change template_ to your themename_ first